Unable to set property 'OnBackdropClick' on object of type 'MudBlazor.MudDialog' in .Net8
After upgrading the project from .NET 7 to .NET 8, many MudBlazor components are not functioning as expected. For example, with MudDialog, if I use OnBackdropClick, I encounter this error:
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to set property 'OnBackdropClick' on object of type 'MudBlazor.MudDialog'. The error was: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Action' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.MouseEventArgs]'.
 ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Action' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.MouseEventArgs]'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.PropertySetter.CallPropertySetter[TTarget,TValue](Action`2 setter, Object target, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.<SetProperties>g__SetProperty|3_0(Object target, PropertySetter writer, String parameterName, Object value)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.<SetProperties>g__SetProperty|3_0(Object target, PropertySetter writer, String parameterName, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.SetProperties(ParameterView& parameters, Object target)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at MudBlazor.State.ParameterSet.SetParametersAsync(Func`2 baseSetParametersAsync, ParameterView parameters)

I set the interactivity of the component to InteractiveServer, but no chance
<MudDialog @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" OnBackdropClick="HandleBackdropClick">

I also set the interactivity of:

HeadOutlet and Routes in the App.razor file
MudThemeProvider, MudDialogProvider and MudSnackbarProvider in the MainLayout.razor file

This issues on GitHub did not help me resolve the error:
#7774 #7510

Might be helpful to see the signature of HandleBackdropClick as its an invalid cast exception

I don't think that is the reason, same implementation works fine in .Net7

It's not likely that interactivity is your issue here. Lack of interactivity means that c# code isn't executed at all in response to user actions, so this exception would not occur since it would never invoke the click method. I'm more inclined to agree with the previous comment

You're right, I mentioned the interactivity only to point out that other errors would have required set the interactivity. In this error something else seems wrong

Can you reproduce the error in https://try.mudblazor.com/

Sorry guys, it was my mistake. I had to update the MudBlazor package in the project.
